# Mongo $lookup filter using nested query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I'm playing with mongoDB's $lookup function, specifically the pipeline syntax, to allow me to perform some more complex queries than the ORM I am using (Sails/Waterline) allows.

A cut down version of my data looks like....

```js
    // 'job' collection
    {
      "id"      : j1,
      "mediaID" : "ABC1234"
    },
    {
      "id"      : j2,
      "mediaID" : "DEF1234"
    },
    {
      "id"      : j3,
      "mediaID" : "FGH3456"
    }
```

..and..

```js
    // 'task' collection

    // j1 tasks
    {
      "id"      : "t1",
      "job"     : "j1",
      "taskName": "MOVE",
      "status"  : "COMPLETE"
    },
    {
      "id"      : "t2",
      "job"     : "j1",
      "taskName": "PUBLISH",
      "status"  : "COMPLETE"
    },
    // j2 tasks
    {
      "id"      : "t3",
      "job"     : "j2",
      "taskName": "MOVE",
      "status"  : "FAILED"
    },
    // j3 tasks
    {
      "id"      : "t4",
      "job"     : "j3",
      "taskName": "MOVE",
      "status"  : "COMPLETE"
    }
```

..where the task collection links to the job collection via `job.id -> task.job`

What I would like to achieve is, to be able to filter jobs by `job.mediaID` and/or also `task.status`. The query I currently have almost gets what I want, but it doesn't filter out the `jobs`, it just doesn't populate the `tasks` part.

My current query is as follows...

```js
    let results = await jobCollection.aggregate([

      // First filter jobs with matching criteria
      {
        $match: {
          $text: {$search: "1234"}
        }
      },

      // Next, link the task collection, and filter by status
      {
        "$lookup": {
          from    : 'task',
          'let'   : {job_id: '$_id'},
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $and: [
                    // This does the linking of job.id -> task.job_id
                    {$eq: ['$job', '$$job_id']},
                    // This filters out unwanted tasks
                    {$eq: ['$status', 'FAILED']}
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          as      : 'tasks'
        }
      }
    ])
    .toArray();
```

In that example, the first stage would match `j1` and `j2` as they both contain "1234", then I would like to further filter out the jobs, based on the task status, for example, only `j2` has a task that has `status==FAILED`, so my end result would just be the `j2` document.

I hope this makes. I think I may just need to add some clever projection on the end. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$match` inside `$lookup` pipeline has no relation with the `jobCollection` documents. It only filters the documents for `tasks` collection. So, You have to use one more `$match` stage after the `$lookup` to filter out the ROOT(`jobCollection`) documents.

```
jobCollection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "$text": { "$search": "1234" }}},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "task",
    "let": { "job_id": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [
            { "$eq": ["$job", "$$job_id"] },
            { "$eq": ["$status", "FAILED"] }
          ]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "tasks"
  }},
  { "$match": { "tasks": { "$ne": [] }}},
])
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it's be something simple I was missing. Still trying to wrap my head around it all.

Comment: Any idea how I might also maintain all the sub-documents in the output, instead of just the matched one?