# Mongodb aggregation lookup query - return all sub-documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236725/mongo-lookup-filter-using-nested-query) question, I am hoping to filter a list of parent documents, based upon values in associated child documents.

Given the following mongoDB collections....

```js
    // 'job' collection
    {
      "id"      : j1,
      "mediaID" : "ABC1234"
    },
    {
      "id"      : j2,
      "mediaID" : "DEF1234"
    }
```

..and..

```js
    // 'task' collection

    // j1 tasks
    {
      "id"      : "t1",
      "job"     : "j1",
      "taskName": "MOVE",
      "status"  : "COMPLETE"
    },
    {
      "id"      : "t2",
      "job"     : "j1",
      "taskName": "PUBLISH",
      "status"  : "FAILED"
    },
    // j2 tasks
    {
      "id"      : "t3",
      "job"     : "j2",
      "taskName": "MOVE",
      "status"  : "COMPLETE"
    },
    {
      "id"      : "t4",
      "job"     : "j2",
      "taskName": "PUBLISH",
      "status"  : "COMPLETE"
    }
```

..where the task collection links to the job collection via job.id -> task.job

I have an aggregate query which will filter `job` collection based upon criteria in child collection. I am using the pipeline syntax of Mongo's `$lookup` and have a query something like this....

```js
db.getCollection("job").aggregate(
  [
    {

      "$lookup": {
        "from"    : "task",
        "let"     : {
          "job_id": "$_id"
        },
        "pipeline": [
          {
            "$match": {
              "$expr": {
                "$and": [
                  {
                    // link job.id to task.job
                    "$eq": ["$job", "$$job_id"]
                  },
                  {
                    // Filter taskName
                    "$eq": ["$taskName", "PUBLISH"]
                  },
                  {
                    // Filter by status
                    "$eq": ["$status", "FAILED"]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "as"      : "tasks"
      }
    },
    {
      // Remove ROOT docs that do not meet 'task' criteria
      "$match": {
        "tasks": {"$ne": []}
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

This works just fine, except that I would like *all* sub-documents of a parent returned in the results, not just the one that matched.

For example, the above query gives me this...

```js
  {
     "id"      : j1,
     "mediaID" : "ABC1234"
     "tasks" : [
         {
           "id"      : "t2",
           "job"     : "j1",
           "taskName": "PUBLISH",
           "status"  : "FAILED"
      },
     ]
   },
```

..but I would like this...

```js
  {
     "id"      : j1,
     "mediaID" : "ABC1234"
     "tasks" : [
         {
           "id"      : "t1",
           "job"     : "j1",
           "taskName": "MOVE",
           "status"  : "COMPLETE"
         },
         {
           "id"      : "t2",
           "job"     : "j1",
           "taskName": "PUBLISH",
           "status"  : "FAILED"
      },
     ]
   },
```

I have an inking I would need to use `$push` at some point, but am stumped! Any help appreciated.

Comment: Then remove the filter by `status` and `taskCode`

Comment: But then it would return the other `job` document! I am looking to filter for jobs that have failed, but I still need to see all the tasks associated with that job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the filtering logic out of `$lookup` and run [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) as a next pipeline stage. There you can use [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) operator to check if there is any subdocument with required values:

```
db.job.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "task",
            localField: "id",
            foreignField: "job",
            as: "tasks"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $anyElementTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$tasks",
                        in: {
                            $and: [
                                { $eq: [ "$$this.taskName", "PUBLISH" ] },
                                { $eq: [ "$$this.status", "FAILED" ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Disclaimer: you have two different field names: `taskName` and `taskCode` in your data / aggregation. I've decided to use the first one.

Comment: Typo fixed! Thanks, this works perfectly and is actually more performant (by 100ms) than my previous method as well as achieving the output I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $addFields.

```
db.job.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {from: 'task', localField: 'id', foreignField: 'job', as: 'taskList'}},
    {$addFields: {
      tasks: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$taskList',
          as: 't',
          cond: { $and: [
              {$eq: ['$$t.taskCode', 'PUBLISH']},
              {$eq: ['$$t.status', 'FAILED']}
          ]}
        }
      }
    }},
    {$project: {
      _id: 1,
      mediaID: 1,
      tasks: 1
    }}
])
```